# Compilation of my wifi driver (RTL8192CE) fails

Tags: debian, compiling, drivers, wifi, realtek

I'm trying to make my wifi work on my newly-installed Debian Sid (amd64, kernel 3.10.11-1). The relevant line of the output of `lspci` is :

```
06:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
```

and this wi-fi card is not recognized :

```
# iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

in case you need it, here is the output of lshw -c network :

```
*-network NON-RÉCLAMÉ   
description: Network controller
produit: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
fabriquant: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
identifiant matériel: 0
information bus: pci@0000:06:00.0
version: 01
bits: 64 bits
horloge: 33MHz
fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
configuration: latency=0
ressources: portE/S:3000(taille=256) mémoire:f1d00000-f1d03fff
```

So I looked up online to find what driver I was supposed to install. I found that I was supposed to go to [this page](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=278&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true) and install the rtl8192ce driver.  I downloaded and extracted it, and followed the instructions of the `readme` file. I changed to super user and tried to compile the driver from the code source with `make`. Here is the output :

```
# make      
make -C /lib/modules/3.10-3-amd64/build M=/home/damien/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013 modules
make[1]: entrant dans le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-3.10-3-amd64 »
  CC [M]  /home/damien/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.o
In file included from /home/damien/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:39:0:
/home/damien/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/pci.h:247:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtl_pci_probe’
 int __devinit rtl_pci_probe(struct pci_dev *pdev,
               ^
/home/damien/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_action_proc’:
/home/damien/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:885:32: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
       rx_status.freq = hw->conf.channel->center_freq;
                                ^
/home/damien/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:886:32: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
       rx_status.band = hw->conf.channel->band;
                                ^
/home/damien/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c: In function ‘rtl_send_smps_action’:
/home/damien/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.c:1451:24: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
   info->band = hw->conf.channel->band;
                        ^
make[4]: *** [/home/damien/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013/base.o] Erreur 1
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/damien/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_88ee_linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013] Erreur 2
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Erreur 2
make[1]: *** [all] Erreur 2
make[1]: quittant le répertoire « /usr/src/linux-headers-3.10-3-amd64 »
make: *** [all] Erreur 2
```

It seems that the error comes from the source code, and not from a lack of library or something.

Any idea of what I should try to do next, or how should I try to solve this compilation error ?

Comment: Did you try to install firmware-realtek and reboot?

Comment: … Damn. I spent two hours on this this morning, and I'm pretty sure it's the first time I see this solution. And I'm not the first one to have had this problem…

It works perfectly now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @schaiba Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please enable contrib and non-free in /etc/apt/sources.list, install `firmware-realtek` and reboot.